# Handling events in the cell of datagridview just like a textbox

Tags: datagridview, custom-controls, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewtextboxcell

I am trying to find out the best way to handle regular textbox events like textchanged , keypress , Enter , KeyDown in a cell of datagridview . The cells would always be in the column0 of the datagridview .I am a new learner in c# . pls share some code to help me out

someone suggested me to use datagridviewtextboxcolumn